# When scrolling in a UIPageViewController, where does the preview image get generated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uipageviewcontroller

In iOS 8, We have a `UIPageViewController` which scrolls between different `xViewControllers`. Similar to what you see on several news sites, where you can scroll between headlines. When you start pushing one page off the screen, the next hugs it, and you can see the next page scroll from offscreen and into place

In the `viewDidLoad` Method of `XviewController`, we change the constraints of the image that is visible on the scrollable pages.

However when we scroll and see a preview of sorts, The preview doesn't have the formatting present in `viewDidLoad`, but will eventually call `viewDidLoad` and the formatting will snap into place once the image has settled in the center of the screen.

So what I'm curious of, is where is the preview ( image that scrolls into place ) generated? It's not generated by either of the UIPageViewDataSource methods

The code is privately owned, so I can't really share it.